# symfony2 load fixtures gives error, please advise on how to fix?

Tags: symfony

i am on part Updating the blog entity where i need to load the fixtures with command:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

but i get an error:

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load
> purging database
> loading Blogger\BlogBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\BlogFixtures
> loading Blogger\BlogBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\CommentFixtures

[ErrorException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 Warning:      file_put_contents(/home/helloises/symfony2/Symfony/app/cache/dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies/Blogge     rBlogBundleEntityBlogProxy.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in     
/home/helloises/symfony2/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php   
line 155
```

please help?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a permission error:

You don't have the write permission in the `app/cache/dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies` directory of your project so doctrine fails to create its proxy classes.

Maybe you gave the write permission to your HTTP server user (so the web works) but not to the  user you used to execute the command.

See the **Setting up Permissions** paragraph in http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup

Comment: i did a chmod 777 on the proxy folder: drwxrwxrwx  2 helloises helloises 4.0K 2012-01-25 12:38 Proxy and -rwxrwxrwx  1 helloises helloises 1.6K 2012-01-16 14:10 ProxyException.php
-rwxrwxrwx  1 helloises helloises  12K 2012-01-16 14:10 ProxyFactory.php
-rwxrwxrwx  1 helloises helloises 1.2K 2012-01-16 14:10 Proxy.php